# SQL Standard Server Transaction Log for an SQL Express Server

Tags: sql-server, transactions

I have an SQL express Server whereby the Transaction log becomes full.
Given the Edition of SQL server it cannot be directly managed with various tools like in the Standard Edition of SQL Server.

We do have another SQL Server - Full Standard version used in this environment as part of a larger system.
*To anticipate the question:* No we cannot add this database to that server.

Is there any way we can utilize the power of Standard SQL server to handle the Transaction logs for the SQL express server?
As if the Transaction Log was being handled by our full SQL Server with the tools available there?

Comment: Sure, you could create a linked server on the standard edition, and a job there that calls `EXEC LinkedServer.master.sys.sp_executesql N'BACKUP LOG ...';` There are of course several other ways to do it; check some of [these answers](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=express+schedule).

Comment: @AaronBertrand that was my thinking that I could do this - but my thoughts were that it was only transaction log and if that was possible. I will investigate this further.

Comment: If you *can't* handle regular backups of your transaction log, perhaps you shouldn't be using a full backup model, and should instead switch to a simple or differential backup model.

Comment: There's an [old article](https://www.sqlteam.com/articles/scheduling-jobs-in-sql-server-express-2) about using Service Broker as an ersatz job scheduler for SQL Express. But @Larnu's recommendation of setting the recovery model to simple recovery might be a better answer depending on the RTO for your database.